# Error: Call to undefined method PHPUnit_Framework_AssertionFailedError::getComparisonFailure()

Tags: cakephp

In CakePHP when writing unit test I keep getting this message:

Error: Call to undefined method PHPUnit_Framework_AssertionFailedError::getComparisonFailure()

What's wrong? Any kind of my own test is not working.

Comment: This would typically mean that the method is not defined. We will need to see your code to be able to help any further.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your attention. I found the solution and it's because using PHPUnit with CakePHP every PHP method must start with a word "test":

```
public function testNewDistance()
```

Comment: otherwise PHPUnit do not recognize the method as a test method